# When giving a noble multiple rooms, do I need to assign each of them separately?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

So most nobles require their own bedroom, dining room, study, and sometimes even a tomb, armour stand and what not. About designating and assigning rooms:

- Do I need to create and assign each of these separately?
- Do they need to be actual separate rooms, or can each piece of furniture be in the same room?
- If rooms are to be separate, should separating doors be set as "internal"?
- Does any of this make a difference in dwarf happiness?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order:

- **Yes**, each room has to be assigned separately and specifically to the noble that will own it.
- **No,** they do not *have* to be separate rooms. You can combine the dining room and the throne room/office by using the same table and chair for each. **HOWEVER**, overlapping rooms mean they both only have *half* the "value" of the entire room, so you'll have to do some serious smoothing, engraving and general prettying up.
- **No.** Setting a door as "internal" only means that it doesn't count as a wall to determine how a room expands/contracts. This is almost certainly not the behavior you want here.
- The general rule is that the prettier (IE, the more valuable) a room is, the better the happy thoughts that are emitted. In the case of an office, this will also apply to any dorf lucky enough to talk to the noble in that office. Also note that a room with a lower quality than the noble requires generates unhappy thoughts, and the idea of a lesser ranking noble -- or *gasp* a commoner! -- owning a better room than they do is a **seriously** unhappy thought...

References (All from DFwiki):

- [Rooms, designation, and quality](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Room)
- [Doors](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Door)
- [Thoughts, happy and otherwise](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Thought)